# Is it possible to set hippie-expand to show up code in a dropdrown menu in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

Is it possible to set hippie-expand to have a dropdown menu in Emacs? Or does Emacs have any completion/expansion system with dropdown menu?

PS: Already tried Company and Auto Complete plugins but their interfere too much with others plugins.

Comment: I wrote [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6556788/324105) to gather hippie expand results, and present them via the ido completion interface. You could adapt the code to use any other completion mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try CEDET suite. it has dropped down completion, if you use graphical interface. i was not able to get drop-down to work in terminal.

CEDET is a bit tricky to set up, but you can follow online tutorials. you can find one by Alex ott, it is one of the better ones.