# How to configure emacs to have it complete the path automatically like vim?

Tags: emacs

I have been a vim user for several years. Now I want to try Emacs for some reasons. I use the path auto-completition functionality(C-c, C-f) a lot in Vim. So I am wondering if there are any similar keystrokes in Emacs ? I have googled this question but only find this answer https://superuser.com/questions/67170/how-do-i-complete-file-paths-in-emacs .However, unlike vim which provides me a list candidate, Emacs completes the first candidate automatically. So, my question is How to configure HippieExpand to make it provide me a list of candidates instead of completing the first candidate automatically ?

Comment: I suggest looking at ido

Comment: I concur with Bwmat. It may not provide the same exact functionality, but [ido](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) is great. If you are using Emacs 22 or later, you already have it. In addition, other modes (e.g. org-mode), allow you to use ido for completion.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to customize HippieExpand to do this, but you might want to take a look at the [auto-complete package](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete). It's fairly easy to set up and offers completion as a drop-down list. It's also very customizable so you can tweak it to behave exactly like you'd prefer. Hope you find it useful!

Edit: I just realized you were looking just for path completion not auto-completion in general. In that case auto-complete.el might be overkill. Still I do suggest that you take a look at it as it offers a lot of added utility. I second taking a look at ido for path-completion.

Comment: On a similar note, there's also http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CompletionUI (which I haven't used)

Comment: @phils: I hadn't heard of this before, it looks like its still in early development. Always good to come across a new emacs package though! :)

Comment: auto-complete will complete filenemes in contexts where you add [ac-source-filename](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#ac-source-filename) to its completion sources (ac-sources). So this is a valid answer, I think.

Comment: @huitseeker: True, I was expressing the opinion that if all OP wanted was to complete filenames then auto-complete might be the proverbial sledgehammer for cracking the path completion nut :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation using hippie-expand, and utilising ido for the selection menu.

This gives us `my-ido-hippie-expand` (which I'm binding to `C-c e`) as the `ido` equivalent of `hippie-expand`, and also makes it easy to generate other targeted expansion utilities using particular expansion functions (typically some sub-set of `hippie-expand-try-functions-list`) which facilitates a filename-only version.

```el
(defun my-hippie-expand-completions (&optional hippie-expand-function)
  "Return the full list of possible completions generated by `hippie-expand'.
The optional argument can be generated with `make-hippie-expand-function'."
  (require 'cl)
  (let ((this-command 'my-hippie-expand-completions)
        (last-command last-command)
        (buffer-modified (buffer-modified-p))
        (hippie-expand-function (or hippie-expand-function 'hippie-expand)))
    (flet ((ding)) ; avoid the (ding) when hippie-expand exhausts its options.
      (while (progn
               (funcall hippie-expand-function nil)
               (setq last-command 'my-hippie-expand-completions)
               (not (equal he-num -1)))))
    ;; Evaluating the completions modifies the buffer, however we will finish
    ;; up in the same state that we began.
    (set-buffer-modified-p buffer-modified)
    ;; Provide the options in the order in which they are normally generated.
    (delete he-search-string (reverse he-tried-table))))

(defmacro my-ido-hippie-expand-with (hippie-expand-function)
  "Generate an interactively-callable function that offers ido-based completion
using the specified hippie-expand function."
  `(call-interactively
    (lambda (&optional selection)
      (interactive
       (let ((options (my-hippie-expand-completions ,hippie-expand-function)))
         (if options
             (list (ido-completing-read "Completions: " options)))))
      (if selection
          (he-substitute-string selection t)
        (message "No expansion found")))))

(defun my-ido-hippie-expand ()
  "Offer ido-based completion for the word at point."
  (interactive)
  (my-ido-hippie-expand-with 'hippie-expand))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c e") 'my-ido-hippie-expand)
```

And the extension of this for just completing filenames:

```el
(defun my-ido-hippie-expand-filename ()
  "Offer ido-based completion for the filename at point."
  (interactive)
  (my-ido-hippie-expand-with
   (make-hippie-expand-function '(try-complete-file-name))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c f") 'my-ido-hippie-expand-filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Notes of interest:

```
;;  For the real hippie-expand enthusiast: A macro that makes it
;;  possible to use many functions like hippie-expand, but with
;;  different try-functions-lists.
;;  Usage is for example:
;;    (fset 'my-complete-file (make-hippie-expand-function
;;                             '(try-complete-file-name-partially
;;                               try-complete-file-name)))
;;    (fset 'my-complete-line (make-hippie-expand-function
;;                             '(try-expand-line
;;                               try-expand-line-all-buffers)))
;;
;;;###autoload
(defmacro make-hippie-expand-function (try-list &optional verbose)
  "Construct a function similar to `hippie-expand'.
Make it use the expansion functions in TRY-LIST.  An optional second
argument VERBOSE non-nil makes the function verbose."
```

You could presumably utilise this to generate a list of possible filename completions.

edit: Actually, that doesn't get you any further than the other question. I'll keep it here, as it seems a slightly nicer approach.

Comment: hi, phils, could you be more specifically ? I am new to emacs so I don't know much about emcas. I have put the following code in my .emacs file but it seems that it didn't work.    (fset 'my-complete-file (make-hippie-expand-function
                             '(try-complete-file-name-partially
                               try-complete-file-name)))
    (fset 'my-complete-line (make-hippie-expand-function
                            '(try-expand-line
                               try-expand-line-all-buffers)))

(defmacro make-hippie-expand-function (try-list &optional verbose)

Comment: The code I posted is an excerpt from the `hippie-exp.el` library in Emacs. You can see it with `M-x find-function RET make-hippie-expand-function RET`. In your case, I think the first of those `(fset)` calls would be relevant. Evaluating that function call (only) gives you a function you can then call with `(my-complete-file ARG)` which is identical to `(hippie-expand ARG)`, except that it only uses the two `try-complete-file-name*` functions when determining completions. On its own, that doesn't solve your problem, but it could be used as part of a solution.