# Auto completion keyword in Emacs

Tags: emacs

for example when I am typing int main() it would be nice if I could just hit tab and get the list of keywords (auto completion) I want. How can I do this in Emacs?

Comment: Emacs is too cool for autocomplete :P I use emacs for the reason that it doesnt have autocomplete by default. That way you learn the code better :) just my two e-cents

Comment: @Jesus: that is true but my friend is saying emacs is uncool because it doesn't have it. So I am trying to convince him that emacs can do anything :)

Comment: It can, if you want I can refer you to an autocomplete that only works with the stuff in any open buffer (not really language specific stuff) I use it on large projects so I don't misspell things sometimes.

Comment: @Jesus: Have you tried "company"? Does that offer language specific auto-completion?

Comment: Sorry not familiar with that. I tend to avoid autocomplete altogether :) who needs an IDE to code

Comment: @Mark never used "company" mode. I use yasnippet and auto-completion mode for auto complete the coede

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can autocomplete with `M-/`. There are also [other autocomplete packages](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete) available.

Comment: `M-/` is bound to `dabbrev-expand` by default. Many people rebind this key to the more comprehensive `hippie-expand` (which incorporates the dabbrev expansion options amongst others).

Comment: FWIW, I also wrote the following answer recently which generates all the `hippie-expand` completions and uses `ido-completing-read` to let the user select the one they want from the minibuffer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515009/how-to-configure-emacs-to-have-it-complete-the-path-automatically-like-vim/6556788#6556788

Answer (score 3):

You need [CEDET](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/), it contains many good tools that can be used to make EMACS have many features that you would see in a more modern IDE.

Comment: You don't *need* CEDET for simple auto completion.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about CEDET I am think I am going to be alot more productive from now on.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [yasnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/). By writing 'main' and then TAB, you get

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

  return 0;
}
```

(This is not really auto completion.)

Comment: @kindahero: sorry, I had not seen your comment.

Comment: Does yashnippet do more than just autocomplete the main? How could I extend it to do more? could you show more examples?

Comment: The package comes bundled with lots of snippet expansions, e.g., 'if' + TAB gives you an 'if' with parentheses, braces for the block, and point inside the parentheses; writing the condition and pressing TAB puts the point inside the braces. You may also create your own snippets; it is pretty simple (no elisp required), see [this](http://yasnippet.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/snippet-development.html)

Answer (score 1):

Asher's answer with the list is probably the best but if you want something that gives you a drop down of possible (non semantic) completions which you can select, you can use [auto complete mode](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/).