# How to show all possible completions hippie-expand command creates in Emacs?

Tags: list, emacs, autocomplete, expand, abbreviation

I want to list all items that `hippie-expand` creates, then choose from them by moving the cursor and hitting RET. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'm using for this purpose:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "M-i") 'complete-with-helm)
(require 'ac-helm)
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
(defun ac-complete-with-helm-auto ()
  "Select `auto-complete' candidates by `helm'.
It is useful to narrow candidates."
  (interactive)
  (let ((c (ac-candidates)))
    (if (= (length c) 1)
        (ac-expand)
      (when ac-completing
        (with-helm-show-completion ac-point ac-last-point
          (helm :sources 'helm-source-auto-complete-candidates
                :buffer  "*helm auto-complete*"))))))
(defun complete-with-helm ()
  (interactive)
  (ignore-errors
    (call-interactively 'auto-complete)
    (call-interactively 'ac-complete-with-helm-auto)))
```

Necessary packages are `auto-complete`, `helm`, and `ac-helm`.
All of them you can get from the package manager.

Comment: It's so complicated and over spec. But it seems useful. I will use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

use company-mode. all the UI issues already resolved in company-mode

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following answer to a similar question a while ago. It uses the ido interface for selection, but it should be straightforward to adapt to another selection interface.

[How to configure emacs to have it complete the path automatically like vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515009/how-to-configure-emacs-to-have-it-complete-the-path-automatically-like-vim/6556788#6556788)

Comment: It seems what I wanted. I need some hacks on hippie-exp.el. It's very hard for me. Anyway thanks.