# get the absolute path of a file without extension

Tags: emacs, elisp

To get the absolute file path without extension in a buffer, e.g. `/home/alice/hello.cpp` -> `/home/alice/hello`, the following code works

```
(concat (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name)) (file-name-base (buffer-file-name)))
```

But it looks too verbose. Is there a much elegant way or a direct function for this?

Comment: Translate this Python code to elisp `"".join([x(buffer-file-name) for x in [file-name-directory, file-name-base]])` ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name))
```

Are you using `auto-complete`? It completes elisp names so I found the function in a second.

Comment: I do use auto-complete. Wondering how does it helped you in finding the function.

Comment: I just entered `(file` and saw a list of odd 20 functions to do with files. It's easy enough to find the right one by name.

Comment: Actually, what I should have done is use this function from my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021313/how-to-show-all-possible-completions-hippie-expand-command-creates-in-emacs/21021441#21021441.
`(file-` gives 50 candidates. Adding helm `ext` filters this to just 3 candidates.

Comment: `apropos-command` and `occur` (`C-u C-h a` & `M-s o`) make a good combination as well, and are there by default. Or `M-x elisp-index-search RET extension RET`, as it happens.

Comment: `apropos-command` doesn't work for me.
`apropos` with "^file-.*" gives me 78 candidates.
`auto-complete` with "file-" gives me 50 candidates (it filters only functions).
And using my method, I'm already in `helm`, so further typing "ext" gives just 3 candidates.

Comment: `occur` with "ext" after `apropos` gives 8 matches

Comment: Oh, I'm not suggesting those default tools are *better* than something that was designed specifically for filtering lists and finding the thing you want :) I was just pointing out that they're there, and can do the job. (Although if something's indexed in the manual, that usually *is* at least as good as any other approach.)

Comment: @abo-abo `M-x apropos RET file.*extension` gives only about eight candidates, with `file-name-sans-extension` being second on top.  A little less guessing, and bit more proper research would take you to the [File Name Components](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Components.html#File-Name-Components) section of the Elisp manual quite fast as well, where the whole matter is comprehensively explained.  Manuals are worth being read, and the elisp reference doubly so :)

Comment: @lunaryorn, I know how to use standard tools. But I prefer to use better stuff when possible.
With about 10 keystrokes I have `(file-name-sans-extension)` already entered in code.
And with one keystroke more, I have in-place argument list or documentation.
Your search string for `apropos` is alone longer than 10 keystrokes, not to mention filtering/selecting/inserting.

Answer (score 0):

If you manipulate files very often in Elisp, i recommend installing [`f.el`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el) file and directory API, which adds a big amount of utility functions. For example, you can use [`f-no-ext`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-no-ext-path) to drop extension from the path.